# Button click handler not being called unless form action is specified 

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.NET web application for data collecting (a webform with two text fields and a Telerik editor, a button for submit with server side OnClick event listener attached).
The event listener saves data on DB and then redirects to another page.
Under development web server the application works fine.
When published under IIS7 the event listener doesn't fire. The only way i found to make it work is to specify the action on the form tag:

```
<form id="form1" action="default.aspx" runat="server">
```

This is the first time this happens to me, i never run into this problem before with other applications (even more complex!).

Did anyone seen this behaviour before? Any (smarter) solutions other than mine?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Firebug, or some other type of development console, which you could see if there are any javascript errors in the production environment?   This could prevent a form from being posted.

Comment: Hi Kyle! Yes, i checked for javascript errors but all the js part of the application (basically some jquery) runs with no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source of the generate html, it will contain the action for the form tag regardless of whether you specify it or not. So can you check what is the action in the resultant html when you don't put action="default.aspx" explicitly.

I have seen similar behaviour when i had implemented some url rewriting, then the generated form action was becoming wrong. I had to set the action in the code behind  to

```
Page.Form.Action = ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/{0}", Path.GetFileName(Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath)));
```

Also can you check that the same behavior is there in both Integrate Pipeline, and classic mode of IIS7.